# REGEXP - Matching Zero or More Occurrences of the Preceding Subexpression

Tags: sql, regex

I am confused as to why my results in the following query appear the way they are. The following is a list of last names from the employees table:

```
Abel
Davies
De Haan
Ernst
Fay
Geraldo
Gietz
Grant
Hartstein
Higgins
Hunold
King
Kochhar
Lorentz
Matos
Mourgos
Rajs
Taylor
Vargas
Whalen
Zlotkey
```

The following query returns the employee last names as well as the REGEXP_SUBSTR operation to find last names that have an 'a' in their last name followed by one or more a's:

```
SQL> select last_name, regexp_substr(last_name,'a+',1,1,'i')
  2  from employees;

LAST_NAME                 REGEXP_SUBSTR(LAST_NAME,'
------------------------- -------------------------
Abel                      A
Davies                    a
De Haan                   aa
Ernst
Fay                       a
Geraldo                   a
Gietz
Grant                     a
Hartstein                 a
Higgins
Hunold
King
Kochhar                   a
Lorentz
Matos                     a
Mourgos
Rajs                      a
Taylor                    a
Vargas                    a
Whalen                    a
Zlotkey
```

Why does the above query return values for the substring when only one 'a' is present, not followed by another 'a'?

In addition, the following query is the identical, but looks for zero or more occurrences of 'a' in the last name:

```
SQL> select last_name, regexp_substr(last_name,'a*',1,1,'i')
  2  from employees;

LAST_NAME                 REGEXP_SUBSTR(LAST_NAME,'
------------------------- -------------------------
Abel                      A
Davies
De Haan
Ernst
Fay
Geraldo
Gietz
Grant
Hartstein
Higgins
Hunold
King
Kochhar
Lorentz
Matos
Mourgos
Rajs
Taylor
Vargas
Whalen
Zlotkey
```

Why does the above query only return a substring for Abel? Shouldn't it display substrings for last names that have 'a' in them?

Please help me understand why these queries behave the way that they do.

EDIT: I am using Oracle Database 12c

Comment: `+`  matches one or more occurrences. To match two or more use `{2,}`.

Comment: The second one does match all strings but since Abel is the only one that starts with A the letter is shown for Abel record only. For the rest, the empty string is output, the one matched at the beginning of a string before the character other than `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 questions in one....

1. The first pattern, you're using a plus.  Plus in regex means one or more.  If you want to match 2 or more, use a{2,} or aa+.
2. In the second one, you're matching 0 or more times.  This should conceivably match any string, since they all contain 0 or more a's.

Comment: Why doesn't the second query behave the way that it is expected to?

Comment: Probably your call to regexp_substr() tells it to match once instead of doing global matching.

Comment: There is no function in Oracle that would do multiple regex matching.